# Matlab - Read and show the tif image

Tags: matlab, tiff

Please checkout the below link which directs an image (tif). It has 4 channels.

http://amarfree.com/Kannada_1_001.tif

Please help me in reading the image and convert it to b/w image using matlab.

Kindly furnish the image channels information.

Comment: See [`imread`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html). You can import an image as a matrix. Then you can write your own script that converts any colour to black. See more information about how the matrix is structured in the help function.

Comment: I have done imread, imshow it shows me error, i dont understand the image information, which has 4 channels.

Answer (score 3):

The fourth channel of your image is the alpha channel. It contains the transparency value of each pixel. In this example, all the values in the 4th channel are identical to 255:

```
sum(sum(I(:,:,4)~=255))

ans =

 0
```

The general solution in this specific case is to ignore the last channel(since it doesn't add information at all), and use rgb2gray function:

```
I = imread('<image path>');
bw = rgb2gray(I(:,:,1:3));
```

However, in your case you don't have rgb2gray function (probably because you don't have Matlab's Image Processing Toolbox). The general solution for this case is to implement a function which converts rgb images into bw images.

Luckily, in this particular example, the 3 channels are completely identical:

```
isequal(I(:,:,1),I(:,:,2))

ans =

 1

isequal(I(:,:,1),I(:,:,3))

ans =

 1
```

Therefore, you can simply write:

```
bw = I(:,:,1);
```

Notice that it will only work **for this particular case**.

Comment: bw = rgb2gray(img(:,:,1:3));
imshow(bw) Undefined function 'rgb2gray' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

Error in scale (line 3)
bw = rgb2gray(img(:,:,1:3));